# Solr returning poor and invalid spelling suggestions

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to find a way to improve the spelling suggestions offered by Solr while still retaining as much of the good suggestions as possible.  One particular search is causing me s a massive headache:

"yellow flowers"

When searching for this Solr offers the suggestions "yellow flowersit"

As far as I can tell this is coming from a section in the field used to generation the suggestions that looks like "flowers. It"

This is only one of many iterations of issues I've had with this particular query (I'm sure their are plenty of others, but I'm focusing on resolving this one).  Previously I had issues with ellipses concatenating words such as:

"flowers...a" => "yellow flowersa"

I've tired various things like adding spellcheck.accuracy to the query, but I found this excluded valid suggestions before it excluded the invalid ones (it excluded "acet" => "acer" at 0.7, but didn't exclude the "flowerse" until 0.9).  I've tried onlyMorePopular to both true and false, neither had an appreciable effect.

I'm considering trying to use thresholdTokenFrequency, but I have a feeling I would lose a lot of valid suggestions for things like proper names that might only appear in the index once.

Along the sames lines: searching for "flowerse" results in suggestions like "flowersse" rather than a more appropriate "flowers" suggestion.

What can I do to improve the results of spelling suggestions, or even just list words to never be suggested or similar?

Why is Solr suggesting such oddball word combinations that can't appear more than a couple times when the search term is one of the most common words in my index?

text fieldType definition:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(…|[\.]{2,})" replacement=" " />
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Suggestions field definition:

`<field name="suggestions" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />`

requestHandler:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">1</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Can you please add the fieldType definition from your schema.xml for the field that the suggestions are being derived from as well as your spelling requestHandler entry from your solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Thanks, done.  I also added the field definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting your fieldType definition. Based on this, I think your issues are related to the use of the EnglishPorterFilterFactory and the WordDelimiterFilterFactory. These two Filter Factories are changing the values that are being tokenized (stored by Solr in the field) to maximize search results. Hence you are being offered these stemmed and delimited values up as spelling suggestions and I believe this is not the behavior you are expecting.

In this scenario, I would recommend using a different fieldType for the suggestions field that removes those two Filter Factories as a starting point to see if your spelling suggestions are improved. Because I believe you want spelling suggestions that are more representative of the values being passed to Solr for indexing, not how Solr is storing them for maximizing search results.

Also please note that the [EnglishPorterFilterFactory has been deprecated](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_0/org/apache/solr/analysis/EnglishPorterFilterFactory.html) and it is recommended that you switch to the [SnowballPorterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Notes_about_solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory) instead.